# SQL sort based on comma-separated string?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say that I have a table that looks like this (sorry about using a picture, but I can't figure out how to get a nicely-formatted table on SO...):

[image: Recipes and Ingredients]

I wanted to make a query to sort the ingredients by the frequency of recipes they appear in. So in this example, we'd want to see the following output:

[image: Sorted ingredients]

I was thinking that LIKE and IN might be potentially helpful to make this search, but I'm not sure how to go from there.

Comment: Fix your data structure so you have a table, say `RecipeIngredients`, with one row per recipe and ingredient.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do this directly with SQL with the current table format. You would have to what @GordonLinoff is saying.

Alternatively, you could extract each row, parse the individual ingredients and count them in a hash for example. If the data set is not too large, it wouldn't be that bad in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks guys! Is there a way such that I could use SQL to programmatically create that additional table, or would I have to connect it to Python or something?

Comment: For formatting tables in questions and answers, you can use `<pre></pre>` html tags.

Answer (score 0):

I really can't resist a "you can't" quote. Your solution follows.

```
SELECT Item
FROM
(
    SELECT LTRIM(x.XmlCol.value('.','varchar(100)')) 'Item'
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(ingredients,',','</A><A>')+'</A>' AS XML) 'Ingredient'
        FROM #recipes ) Mytab
    CROSS APPLY Mytab.Ingredient.nodes('/A') x(xmlcol)
) Listing
GROUP BY ITEM
ORDER BY Count(1) DESC
```

Try it for yourself. In short you start by replacing the commas with XML seperators, Then for efficiency invoke Microsofts own XML methods to convert the list of values into a tabular output. You then simply drop the lot into a FROM statement and group with an order by.